# nginx nodejs proxy_pass 404 The path matches but I get a 404 error, why?

Tags: nginx

nginx proxy_pass question.
I'm working on uploading a video with nginx proxy pass.

This suddenly didn't work, so I'm asking a question;

this is yml conf

```yml
vod:
  limit-size: 5000000000
  host-name: domain.com/uploader
  uploader-port:443
```

nginx conf

```nginx
#VOD upload
    

location /uploader {


    proxy_set_header    Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header    X-NginX-Proxy true;

    proxy_pass http://localhost:3009/uploader;   
}
```

this is node.js upload module

```properties
SITE_DOMAIN=http://127.0.0.1
PORT=3009
SSL_USE=N
SSL_PORT=3001
SSL_KEY_FILE_PATH=C:/Program Files/OpenSSL-Win64/bin/private.key
SSL_CERT_FILE_PATH=C:/Program Files/OpenSSL-Win64/bin/sslProxy.crt
SSL_CA_FILE_PATH=C:/Program Files/OpenSSL-Win64/bin/proxyCA.crt
SSL_PASSWORD=
UPLOAD_CONTEXT_PATH=/uploader
TMP_DIR=/vod/tigen/TG_LIVE/upload/temp/
LOGS_DIR=/home/tigen/live/vod-uploader/logs/
```

I confirmed that the video was uploaded normally until the 3/15th, and when I uploaded it as a test from last week, an error suddenly appeared.
I kept getting a 404 error, so I looked it up because I thought it was a path problem, and the path seems to fit, but I don't know why it's an error.

It's ridiculous because this happened and it didn't work

I am attaching the screen error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMykJ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/244Eu.png)

please help me

Tried changing nginx config but failed

- nginx access.log file

[04/Apr/2023:11:13:55 +0900] "GET /uploader/css/icon/mp4.svg HTTP/1.1" 404 164 "https://example.com/admin/vod/vodWriteForm.do" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36

[04/Apr/2023:11:13:55 +0900] "GET /admin/uploader/css/icon/etc.svg HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "https://example.com/admin/vod/vodWriteForm.do" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

Comment: Your location looks correct. Is the proxy_pass target correct, and is the Node server the one actually returning the 404? You could test this from the outside by adding some extra header from the Node server's response on 404s. It's also unclear what that YAML is for, and your Node app's environment variables aren't too useful — the code handling uploads would be more useful here.

Comment: Thank you for answer This project sends a request from springboot to nginx to upload a video. The yml setting is for receiving variables from html and sending requests to the upload javascript file. Currently, I was testing by putting an absolute path in the url like this.

Comment: if(fileArr.length > 0) {
  var uploaderProtocol = window.location.protocol;
  var hostName = /*[[${dto.vodHostName}]]*/ '';

  var url ="https://live.artmore.kr/uploader/chunkUpload";
  uploadContentsInit();

  $("#uploadContents").modal({backdrop: 'static'});
  $("#uploadContents").modal('show');

  tg1st_fileUpload(url, vodEncoding);

Comment: if(!piece.uploadPause) {
  setCookie(piece.id, piece, 7);
  abortXhr = xhr;
  xhr.send(formData);
 } else {
  var trId = "tr_" + fileArr[currIdx].id;
  var tr = $("#uploadContentsTable > tbody").find("#" + trId);
  var td = tr.children();
  
  td.eq(4).text("대기중");
 }

Comment: The code to handle the upload is too long, so if you look at the snippets, this part of xhr.send throws an error.

Comment: Please don't put code in comments, it's hard to read. You can [edit your question here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75924764/edit) and add the code. The client-side uploader code is also probably not relevant (though there are easier ways than using `xhr`); the important thing is what's behind that `location https://127.0.0.1:3009`. I assumed the thing listening on 3009 was a Node server because you mentioned Node — whatever it is, does it still accept a formdata post at that path? You can also get more information by checking your Nginx logs.

Comment: It's my first time asking a question, so I should have been more careful, but I made a mistake, I'm sorry I modified the nginx log and registered again. error.log is not recorded, only access.log is recorded.

Comment: 실수하는 건 괜찮아요! No need to apologize, this platform takes a little while to learn (I recommend reading the documentation, it does help!)

From your access logs, there is a 404 coming from the Java backend, but it doesn't seem relevant to this specific problem. Error logs or other changes to your Nginx logging config could be useful. From my testing, it looks like your backend (that you're proxying to) probably doesn't handle a FormData post at /uploader/chunkUpload, though.

Comment: Thank you. Looking at the last screen error, it says Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).The suspicious situation is that the file is moved using the winSCP program. Can this happen if the file is partially corrupted and sent while moving the file? It was working fine 3 weeks ago

Comment: I don't know anything at all about WinSCP, or about WinSCP.dll if the relevant code is using that. I don't think you'll be able to get a fix here on StackOverflow because there isn't enough context that you can probably share — I recommend looking through Git logs (or Bash/shell history if changes have been made on the server directly), and adding in more logs in the backend application to see if that path is actually being hit, and then opening a new question if you've narrowed it down but can't figure out the fix. Right now, there's not enough information and too many possible issue areas.